# uninitialized collection shown when procedure is called in pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I have seen the other similar questions but I cannot understand what is the problem in my code. The following is the procedure definition

**Proc.sql**

```
set serveroutput on

create or replace type myarray is varray(1000) of number;
/ 
create or replace procedure Bill(cid in number , bill out number) is
md myarray;
q myarray;
pr myarray;
rs myarray;
begin
bill:=0;
select model,quantity BULK COLLECT into md,q from transactions where customer=cid;

for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
select price BULK COLLECT into pr from computers where model_no=md(i);
END LOOP;

for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
rs(i):=q(i)*pr(i);
end loop;



for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
bill:=bill+rs(i);
end loop;

end;
/
show errors;
```

and this is my file for calling the procedure

**CallProc.sql**

```
set serveroutput on
declare
bll number(2):=0;
begin
Bill(1,bll);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('T = '|| bll);
end;
/
```

Comment: `rs` doesn't appear to be initialised.

Comment: initializing rs shows this error :
ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
ORA-06512: at "R1507108.BILL", line 15

Comment: Yes, initialising creates an empty collection, so there is no `rs(i)` to set. You'll need to extend it to match `md`, or else change it to an associative array as these can be sparse.

Comment: still not working . Showing same error .

Comment: If the subscript is beyond the count, then you can't have extended it enough. Anyway, see Alex Poole's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you initialise the array as an empty collection:

```
declare
  ...
  rs myarray := myarray();
begin
```

then you have to [increase its capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-03F74821-BC33-4544-9304-5FBBE6EFE450), either as you go around the loop:

```
for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
  rs.extend;
  rs(i):=q(i)*pr(i);
end loop;
```

or in one go (which should be more efficient):

```
rs.extend(md.COUNT);
for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
  rs(i):=q(i)*pr(i);
end loop;
```

You still have to initialise the empty collection before you extend it.

---

You have other issues though. You are doing:

```
rs(i):=q(i)*pr(i);
```

but the `rs` and `pr` collections are completely independent, so their indices have no relationship. I think you are trying to add records to `pr` each time round this loop:

```
for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
select price BULK COLLECT into pr from computers where model_no=md(i);
END LOOP;
```

but what you are actually doing is *replacing* the entire contents of the collection with a single value, not appending; and at the end of that loop you will only have the price for the last row in the `md` collection. The only `i` value that is valid for that collection is 1, as only `pr(1)` exists (assuming `model_no` is unique); and unless the customer only has one transaction that won't be the right price, except for the last model (where i != 1).

You could just get the relevant price inside the loop, without a collection for that:

```
create or replace procedure Bill(cid in number , bill out number) is
  md myarray;
  q myarray;
  pr number; -- scalar variable
  rs myarray := myarray();
begin
  select model, quantity bulk collect into md, q from transactions where customer=cid;

  rs.extend(md.COUNT);
  for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
    select price into pr from computers where model_no=md(i); -- not bulk collect
    rs(i):=q(i)*pr; -- pr no longer indexed
  end loop;

  bill:=0;
  for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
    bill:=bill+rs(i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

It would be more efficient to get the prices aligned with the rest of the data by joining the tables and doing a single bulk collect into all three collections:

```
create or replace procedure Bill(cid in number , bill out number) is
  md myarray;
  q myarray;
  pr myarray;
  rs myarray := myarray();
begin
  select t.model, t.quantity, c.price
  bulk collect into md, q, pr
  from transactions t
  join computers c on c.model_no = t.model
  where t.customer = cid;

  rs.extend(md.COUNT);
  for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
    rs(i):=q(i)*pr(i);
  end loop;

  bill:=0;
  for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
    bill:=bill+rs(i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

But then you can simplify further by doing both calculations in one loop:

```
  bill:=0;
  rs.extend(md.COUNT);
  for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
    rs(i):=q(i)*pr(i);
    bill:=bill+rs(i);
  end loop;
```

and from that you can see you don't really need `rs` at all, you can just calculate the bill change directly:

```
create or replace procedure Bill(cid in number , bill out number) is
  md myarray;
  q myarray;
  pr myarray;
begin
  select t.model, t.quantity, c.price
  bulk collect into md, q, pr
  from transactions t
  join computers c on c.model_no = t.model
  where t.customer = cid;

  bill:=0;
  for i in 1..md.COUNT loop
    bill := bill + q(i)*pr(i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

But you don't need loops or collections at all:

```
create or replace procedure Bill(cid in number , bill out number) is
begin
  select sum(t.quantity * c.price)
  into bill
  from transactions t
  join computers c on c.model_no = t.model
  where t.customer = cid;
end;
/
```

and obviously you could just run that query as plain SQL without involving PL/SQL or a procedure at all.

Depends what your assignment is telling you to use...

Comment: showing this error :ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "R1507108.BILL", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 4

Comment: You have to do both parts - initialise *and* extend. You have a bigger problem though, in that you're using `pr(i)` - but there is no connection between the indices for the `md` and `pr` collections. The whole approach is odd - is this an assignment that specifically has to use bulk collect and collections?